# How to stop Fluently.Configure connecting automatically

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, inversion-of-control, unity-container, informix

How can I prever Fluently.Configure connection to the DB automatically?

Our setup is detailed below.

We have the following static method to create a session factory:

```
public static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
        {
          return Fluently.Configure()
              .Database(
                 IfxOdbcConfiguration
                .Informix
                .ConnectionString("DSN=ODBCCONNECTION")
                .Driver<CompanyCore.Nhibernate.Core.ProfiledODBCClientDriver>()
                .Dialect<InformixDialect1000>()
                .ShowSql() 
              )
              .Mappings(
              m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Task>()
              )
              .BuildSessionFactory();
        }
```

Which is used with our IOC setup to create the SessionFactory, however, due to what is required by our DB team, each user must open his/her own connections as their user (Using impersonalisation) - to allow for process identification, to see who is running what on the Informix server.

To create the individual connections we use:

```
public static ISession GetMySession(ISessionFactory factory, string user)
{
    CompanyCore.Nhibernate.Core.ProfiledODBCClientDriver drv = new Enact.Nhibernate.Core.ProfiledODBCClientDriver();

    drv.Configure(new Dictionary<string, string>());

    string conn = "DSN=ODBCCONNECTION";

    IDbConnection db = drv.CreateConnection();

    db.ConnectionString = conn;
    db.Open();

    return factory.OpenSession(db);
}
```

These connections are closed when our UOW calls dispose.

We call `CreateSessionFactory()` on APP Start and then pass this factory around with IOC, but at this point there is no impersonalisation user, and thus causes a app error on first load.

We have thought about using a standard user which has access for things like first load, but surely there is a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to disable the automatic-keyword-quoting:
configuration.SetProperty(Environment.Hbm2ddlKeyWords, "none")

See this post on "Prevent NHibernate to connect to the database on configuration.BuildSessionFactory()" for more details:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/nhusers/F8IxCgYN038

Comment: Perfect - props for the extra link too +1